# Spring Boot RestTemplate issue with HTTPS requests

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, https, resttemplate

I have an issue with RestTemplate HTTPS requests that I'm sending to third party server. Every second request is successful. On every first HTTPS request I'm getting two types of errors:

1. **Software caused connection abort: recv failed SSLException**
2. **Server failed to respond I/O Exception**

Those two errors occurred always on first request and on second one everything works fine.  Here is the configuration of Http request factory:

```
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException 
{
    TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;

    SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
            .build();

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
        .build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

    return restTemplate;
}
```

I researched a lot, but I have found only hints to increase the read timeout that was problematic in first implementation of `getRestTemplate(...)` method. Now is not limited.

Here is the tech stack:

- Java 1.8
- Spring Boot 1.5.7.RELEASE
- HttpClient 4.4.1.
- Apache Tomcat 9.0.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it only the *very first* request which produces the error, or is it every other request (i.e. `error`, `ok`, `error`, `ok`, ...)?

Comment: It's only on very first request and that request produce an error. After few hours, happened again. When I restart Tomcat then the first request is ok, if is requested immediately, if not, same error happened.

Comment: Are you able to ask the third party server maintainer as to whether there any any SSL-related errors in the server log? It sounds like the server is closing the connection, for whatever reason. Alternatively, I would suggest turning on `DEBUG` logs to perhaps try and see if they offer any deeper insight into what exactly the client is trying to send and see if it differs on the second request.

Comment: I have set LOGGER.info(...) on every method on third party server. I've also implemented web services that are receiving the requests. But neither requests are getting on that server. Probably the client is closing the connection.

Comment: I meant turning on `DEBUG` logs on the client. It sounds like - for whatever reason, the SSL handshake is failing the first time around. With `DEBUG` logs in your client code (either for the `RestTemplate` itself or for the deeper wire code, i.e. `HttpClient`), you should see a difference between the first request and the one after that if the issue is consistently reproducible.